# using percentage instead of pixels for videojs

Tags: video.js

I need to have my video play at 100%, but have the size constrain. I tried changing my 1280x720 pixel dimensions to percent, but it didn't work. I also did not see this in the docs. Can I do this? Are there any code samples out there that show this working?

Thanks-
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're on the latest version of Video.js and that the parent element of Video.js has width/height for video.js to be a percentage of. In this example I had to set the html/body to 100% in order for video.js to go to 100%

http://jsbin.com/aLEPoBa/3/edit